# Not getting notified of comments and answers

Tags: bug, notifications

I just [asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21505417/integer-function-result-value-assigned-to-function-name-never-used) and there were a couple comments (now deleted) and an answer, but Stack Overflow never notified me in the top bar. I did however have the question page opened.

"Why the hell aren't I notified of these things?"

[image: Why the hell aren't I notified of these things?]

**UPDATE**

Shortly after, it started working again.

Comment: Did you have a notifications tab open in any window on any computer? This immediately accepts the notification

Comment: @RichardTingle Nope, sure didn't. I only had that particular question open.

Comment: That is weird then. We'll have to wait for a dev to see if there was a temporary glitch. But transient problems are always a nightmare

Comment: To make things even more strange, the first upvote someone did on this particular question showed `+1` in my top bar, but the second upvote showed the proper `+5`.

Comment: That seems to be all over the place. The rational explanation is that you had some down votes as well but to be honest there are regularly times when I can't figure out where the number came from

Comment: @RichardTingle No, I mean this particular SE question, not the linked SO question. No downvotes, just 2 upvotes. The first one the top-bar showed `+1` and the second one showed `+5`

Comment: @RichardTingle I didn't actually get just +1, I did indeed get +5, but the top-bar for some reason showed +1, until I clicked it and saw +5

Comment: As I say it can be a bit eccentric sometimes.  Sometimes I don't understand where it gets its numbers from

Comment: @AlienArrays Well I wasn't necessarily looking for an answer as much as I was just reporting an issue